# React component prop style

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using from UI Materials the  
(https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/) 
component and I want to style the helper text.

[image]

I've tried

```
pstyle = {
  "& div p": {
    textAlign: "right"
  }
}
```

and then pass it as `style={this.pstyle}` and it does not work.

Does anyone has a solution?
Thanks!

Update: This is the component and it's props: https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/
What am I trying to style is the helperText prop

Comment: I don't believe you can use`&` in react style properties that way? I'd be happy to be proved wrong!

Comment: @OliverRadini I've found something similar here at no. 4 https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822

Comment: I'm struggling to find a good example of that in the article you've linked. There's some uses of something similar in the styled components section, but that's a little different to what you're doing here

Comment: Did my response help in any way?

Comment: @rdarioduarte Hello and thanks for the welcome message. I am trying to implement the css as we speak. I'll keep you updated

Comment: Awesome, glad that it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all welcome!

As OliverRadini said, you cannot use `&` in the way you proposed, and this makes sense, since you are directly targeting a specific element, it is not required to start making complex selectors.

Talking about your task at hand, remember that `TextField` component in Material UI library is just a wrapper component for a complete form control including a label, input and help text.

Bare in mind that using Material UI components is aligned with [Google's Material Design patterns](https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html), so the idea is to stick with their guidelines, but if you want to customize, this is what you can do, either use `FormHelperTextProps` as prop in the `TextField` or instead of using the `TextField` wrapper, just break it into its pieces (FormControl, InputLabel, Label, FormHelperText)

The first option is the easiest way to do it for simple customization as the one you want to achieve. Try something like:

Your CSS class

```
projDescHelperText: {
    textAlign: "right"
}
```

Your Component

```
<TextField
    id="project-description"
    label="Project Description"
    helperText="(0/300)"
    FormHelperTextProps={className={classes.projDescHelperText}}
    value={this.state.description}
/>
```

If you have some of your code you can share, I would be able to better tailor a response to you

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set `{ "p": { textAlign: "right" } }` instead of `{ "& div p": { textAlign: "right" } }`

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
<div styles={{textAlign: 'right'}}>
 <p> 0/300</>
</div
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've done it like this:

```
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
    const style = {
  smth: {
    "& p": {
        textAlign: "right !important"
      }
  }
}

<TextField
    className={classes.smth}
  />
export default withStyles(style)(CustomTextField);
```

seems to be working fine for now. Thanks all for the help and the promptitude and @rdarioduarte your solution helped me a lot. Thanks a lot guys!